# Finding lambda of Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

Suppose I have a case like

```
T(n)=2T(n/4)+log(n). a=2, b=4, f(n)=log(n)
```

That should be case 1 because `n^(1/2)>log(n)`. There is also a lambda in case 1. `f(n)=O(n^((1/2)-lambda)`. Is this correct? And how can I find this lambda?

Comment: yes, lambda is a constant > 0

Answer (score 0):

The constant lambda *is* important: its purpose is to avoid considering the bizarre cases that lie between Case 1 and Case 2. Since big-O is an upper bound only and not a lower bound, smaller choices of lambda are "better" in the sense that they cover more functions. Since lambda must be positive, however, there is no "best" choice of lambda. Lambda = 10^-3 should get you through enough examples to see why most treatments of the Master Theorem do not make a production out of choosing lambda.

Comment: Okay, and what is the solution of this recurrence?
T(n)=n^(1/2)?

Answer (score 0):

f(n)=logn

Epsilon can be 1/4 since

n<sup>(log<sub>b</sub>a-epsilon)</sup>=n<sup>(log<sub>4</sub>2-1/4)</sup>=n<sup>(1/2-1/4)</sup>=n<sup>(1/4)</sup>.

f(n)=O(n<sup>(1/4)</sup>).

So by case 1 of the master theorem T(n)=Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)=Θ(n<sup>(1/2)</sup>).